# reduce/ reduce conflict - yacc (identifier)

Tags: yacc

I'm trying to write parser for c simple. The error I get is : "reduce /reduce conflict"

1) Rule **exp** need to get to **IDENTIFIER** 
  for example: **a-b**(identifier-identifier)-> **exp-exp**->**exp**

2) Rule **ident_list** also need to get to **IDENTIFIER** . This rule is used for      variable declaration. 
  for example: **a,b,c**(identifier,identifier,identifier)-> **ident_list** .

Therefor i need both of rules, **ident_list** and **exp** to go to ->**IDENTIFIER**  .This is causing the "reduce /reduce conflict". Any idea how to solve this?

```
-------------*yac code*:---------------


%{
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>
        typedef struct node
        {
                char* token;
                struct node* left;
                struct node* right;
                char* type;
        }node;
         typedef struct obj
        {
                char* type;
                char* name;
                struct obj* next;


        }obj;

         typedef struct symTbl
        {
                struct obj* first;
                struct obj* last;
                int size;
        }symTbl;


        node* mknode (char* token,node* left, node* right,char* Type);
        void put(symTbl* tbl, char* type,char* name);
        void printtree(node* tree);
        #define YYSTYPE struct node*
%}
%start s
%token WHILELOOP
%token STATIF
%token ELSE
%token MAIN
%token POINTERERR
%token COMMENT
%token POINTER
%token GREATEREQUAL
%token LESSEREQUAL
%token DBLAND
%token GREATER
%token LESSER
%token POWER
%token MULTIPLY
%token MINUS
%token PLUS
%token AND
%token OR
%token NOT
%token NOTEQUAL
%token CHARERROR
%token STRINGERROR
%token POINTER
%token INTEGER
%token BOOLEAN
%token DEVIDE
%token ASSIGN
%token EQUAL
%token TYPE
%token IDENTIFIER
%token HEX IF
%token LITERCHAR
%token OCTAL
%token BINARYINT
%token LTRLSTRING
%token COMMA COLON SEMICOLON VAR RETURN RPARENC LPARENC
%left COMMA LPAREN RPAREN ELSE
%left PLUS IF WHILELOOP TYPE
%left MINUS DEVIDE RPARENC LPARENC
%left MULTIPLY EQUAL NOTEQUAL OR AND LESSEREQUAL GREATEREQUAL GREATER LESSER
%%
s:progrem{printtree($1);}
        progrem:exp|var_dec|if_stnt|ident_list|bool_exp| mul_ident;

        exp: exp PLUS exp{$$=mknode("+",$1,$3,"arit");}
            |exp MINUS exp {$$=mknode("-",$1,$3,"arit");}
            |exp DEVIDE exp {$$=mknode("/",$1,$3,"arit");}
            |exp MULTIPLY exp {$$=mknode("*",$1,$3,"arit");}
            |MINUS exp {$$=mknode("-",$2,NULL,"arit");}
            |IDENTIFIER {$$=mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL,"id");}
    |LPAREN exp RPAREN {$$= $2;};
        bool_exp : exp EQUAL exp {$$=mknode("=",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp NOTEQUAL exp {$$=mknode("!=",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp OR exp {$$=mknode("||",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp AND exp {$$=mknode("&&",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp GREATEREQUAL exp {$$=mknode(">=",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp LESSER exp {$$=mknode("<",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp LESSEREQUAL exp {$$=mknode("<=",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |exp GREATER exp {$$=mknode(">",$1,$3,"bool");}
            |LPAREN bool_exp RPAREN {$$= $2;};


          var_dec:ident_list COLON  ident_list {$$=mknode(":",$1,$3,"dec");};

          ident_list: ident_list COMMA ident_list {$$=mknode(",", $1, $3,"id_list");}
                    |ident_list TYPE ident_list{$$=mknode(yytext,$1,NULL,"id");}
                    |VAR {$$= mknode("var",NULL,NULL,"id");}
                    |SEMICOLON  {$$= mknode(";",NULL,NULL,"id");};
                    |IDENTIFIER {$$=$1;}


         if_stnt:IF LPAREN bool_exp RPAREN  {$$=mknode("if",$3,NULL,"if_state");};
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
main()
{
        yyin=fopen("text.txt","r");
        return yyparse();
}
node* mknode( char* token,node*left,node* right,char* Type)
{

        node* newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        char* newstr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
        char* type = (char*)malloc (sizeof(Type)+1);
        type[sizeof(token)]='\0';
        newstr[sizeof(token)]='\0';
        strcpy(newstr,token);
        strcpy(type,Type);
        newnode->left=left;
        newnode->type=type;
        newnode->right=right;
        newnode->token=newstr;
        return newnode;
}

 void put(symTbl* tbl, char* type,char* name)
{
         symTbl* tbl1=(symTbl*)malloc(sizeof(symTbl));

        int size = tbl->size;
        obj* newobj=(obj*)malloc(sizeof(obj));
        newobj= tbl->first;
        int i;
                for( i =0; i<size; i++){
                        if(newobj->name == name){

 yyerror();
                        newobj=newobj->next;
                }
           }
        tbl->last->next=newobj;
        tbl->last=tbl->last->next;

}

void printtree(node* tree)
{

        printf("%s",tree->token);
        if(tree->left)printtree(tree->left);
        if(tree->right)printtree(tree->right);
}
int yyerror()
{
        printf("bla bla\n");
        return 0;
}
```

--------*lex code*:------------

```
minus "-"
colon ":"
semicolon ";"
space " "
parcent "%"
backslash "/"
charptr charptr
plus "+"
not "!"
notequal "!="
or "||"
and "&&"
multiply "*"
power "^"
dbland "&"
greater ">"
lesser "<"
type boolean|string|char|integer|intptr|charptr
return "return"
greaterequal {greater}{assign}
lesserequal {lesser}{assign}
singleQuotes \'
charERR {singleQuotes}+(({digit})+)*(({letter})+)*{singleQuotes}+
stringERR {doubleQuotes}{doubleQuotes}+|{doubleQuotes}
doubleQuotes \"
var "var"{space}*
octalDigit [1-7]
decimal {digit}|{digitNoZero}{digit}+
digitNoZero[1-9]
octal "0"{octalDigit}("0")*{octalDigit}*
integer {binaryInt}|{hex}|{octal}|{decimal}
binaryInt ("0"|"1")+"b"
hexLetter A|B|C|D|E|F
hex 0(x|X){digit}+{hexLetter}*|0(x|X){digit}*{hexLetter}+
literBool true|false
letter [a-zA-Z]
letters {letter}+
digit [0-9]
low "_"
equal "=="
assign "="
devide "/"
lparen "("
rparen ")"
lparenc "{"
rparenc "}"
identifier {letter}+{digit}*{letter}+{space}*|{space}*{letter}{space}*
literChar {singleQuotes}{letter}{singleQuotes}
ltrlString {doubleQuotes}{letters}*{decimal}*{hex}*{octal}*{binaryInt}*{dbland}*{devide}*{assign}*{equal}*{greater}*{lesser}*{greaterequal}*{lesserequal}*{mi$
pointer {colon}{space}{charptr}|"="{space}"&"{identifier}
comment {backslash}{parcent}{space}*({letters}*{space}*{identifier}*{space}*{decimal}*{space}*{hex}*{space}*{octal}*{space}*{binaryInt}*{space}*{dbland}*{dev$
pointerErr "&"{identifier}|{charptr}
statif "if"{space}*
ELSE "else"{space}*
comma ","
whileLoop "while"{space}*
main "main"
%%
{lparen} return LPAREN;
{rparen} return RPAREN;
{colon} return COLON;
{type} return TYPE;
{semicolon} return SEMICOLON;
{var} return VAR;
{whileLoop} return WHILELOOP;
{ELSE} return ELSE;
{statif} return IF;
{pointerErr} return POINTERERR;
{comment} return COMMENT;
{pointer} return POINTER;
{literChar} return LITERCHAR;
{charERR} return CHARERROR;
{stringERR} return STRINGERROR;
{ltrlString} return LTRLSTRING;
{binaryInt} return BINARYINT;
{octal} return OCTAL;
{hex} return HEX;
{return} return RETURN;
{greaterequal} return GREATEREQUAL;
{lesserequal} return LESSEREQUAL;
{dbland} return DBLAND;
{greater} return GREATER;
{lesser} return LESSER;
{lparenc} return LPARENC;
{rparenc} return RPARENC;
{power} return POWER;
{multiply} return MULTIPLY;
{plus} return PLUS;
{or} return OR;
{and} return AND;
{comma} return COMMA;
{not} return NOT;
{main} return MAIN;
{notequal} return NOTEQUAL;
{minus} return MINUS;
{integer} return INTEGER;
{literBool} return BOOLEAN;
{identifier} return IDENTIFIER;
{equal} return EQUAL;
{assign} return ASSIGN;
{devide} return DEVIDE;
. return yytext[0];
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. What's a variable declaration supposed to look like?

Comment: What is the origin of this style of making an enormous list of flex macro definitions only to use them exactly once slightly lower down in the file? Could it be that some textbook actually suggests doing that? Is it the warped idea of some college instructor? If so, could you pass me their email address so that I can complain directly to them?

Comment: Also, your file triggers a bison error because `mul_ident` is referenced but not defined. Read [ask] with particular reference to the idea of a [mcve]

Comment: rici that style is just misunderstanding of my team mate. we realy short in time thats why this is still look like that. thank you guys for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that a `program` can be either an `exp` or an `ident_list`, among other things. This is not particularly sensible to start with, and I suppose your intention is to do some sort of debugging. But it is not going to work because a single identifier could be an expression or a list containing exactly one identifier, and there is no obvious way for the parser to guess which one you meant. That makes your grammar ambiguous.

What yacc/bison does in this case is to choose whichever production comes earlier in the grammar file. That's not a very precise way of defining a preference, so it warns you about the conflict. But it makes it possible for you to express your preference.

Otherwise, you'd have to eliminate the ambiguity. If, for example, you decided that a single identifier should be an `exp`, you could insist that a top-level identifier list have at least two identifiers.

Comment: Seems like `exp` would allow for some quite bizarre results if it cared about ident_lists rather than identifiers, though.

Comment: @cHao: Indeed, but it doesn't. Other than at the top level, `ident_list` is only used in declarations, where it cannot be confused with an `ident`.

Comment: `progrem` can also be `exp`, though. If it can be `exp` or `ident_list`, what does a single identifier get parsed as?

Comment: @cHao: ah, I see what you're saying. I'll redraft the answer.

Comment: Makes more sense now :)